# include different controllers based upon whether the user is logged in or not

Tags: angularjs

I want to include some controllers if the user user is logged in. Acutally, I want to not include some controllers if the user is not logged in

```
    <html ng-app>
        <head data-ng-controller="gamesController">
            <script src="/static/js/app/app.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
            <script src="/static/js/app/controllers.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
            <% if {{ $scope.loggedIn }} %>
               <script src="/static/js/app/controllers/games/games.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
            <% end %>
        </head>
    <body>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Is this possible?
Would I just use a controller to set the $scope.loggedIn value upon loading the page/app.  There are reasons to put the include for app.js at the bottom of the page, but in this scenario, it would seem that app.js would need to be above the if condition.

```
controllers.js
    app.controller('gamesController', ['$scope', function($scope) {
        $scope.loggedIn = "true"; 

    }]);
```

is this the correct approach?

thanks

Comment: adding `ng-controller` to `head` tag is wrong

Comment: Why is this wrong?  Just curious.  What would be the recommended approach to do this?

Comment: please see [this](https://github.com/ocombe/ocLazyLoad) may be help you.